# xaml change image source

Tags: c#, image, xaml

In c# I am making an application using the xaml designer.

PROBLEM: IF I CHANGE THE IMAGE SOURCE INTO ANOTHER IMAGE SOURCE, NOTHING APPEARS: THOUGH, IF THE IMAGE WAS ALREADY DEFINED, IT CHANGED INTO "NULL" (NO IMAGE)

I have used a method (which I found on the web) to change an imagesource (string) into an image(object).

I've tried multiple times to change the image source of some xaml pictures by just changes the imagesource in xaml into another image (that I put in the project)  but unfortunately the image is not visible when I do it this way.

The image and method I used are the following ones:

ms-appx:///Assets/bank_employee.jpg"

```
imageFromXaml.Source = imgCreatedFromMethod.Source;

private static Image srcToImage(string source)   
{   
        Uri imageUri = new Uri(source);    
        BitmapImage imageBitmap = new BitmapImage(imageUri);   
        Image img = new Image();   
        img.Source = imageBitmap;    
        return img;
}
```

Does anyone of you know what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and this worked for me:

```
            var imageSource = new BitmapImage();
            imageSource.BeginInit();
            imageSource.StreamSource = memoryStream;
            imageSource.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            imageSource.EndInit();
```

Comment: (Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) - this message displays. Do you know which reference I should add?

Comment: It is working if you're using Windows forms, but is it also working if you're using Xaml?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried binding the source in XAML to a URI and then updating that?

Like this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}" />
```

Then having a property somewhere in your datacontext which would be like:

```
public class myClass: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private Uri imageUri;

    public Uri ImageUri
    {
        get
        {
            return imageUri;
        }
        set
        {
           imageUri = value;
           if(PropertyChanged != null)
           {
               PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ImageUri"));
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have never tried to bind a component of a XAML GUI but I think it might be good to use it now. Thanks, I will try to implement this in my application.

Comment: @Klyner You should definitely look into databinding it is one of the most useful features of XAML.

Comment: Thanks for your tip!

Btw: what do you have to do to let the following code work?
       
PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ImageUri")); c# can't find the methods

Comment: You need to make sure your class implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and add a property changed event handler...public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

Comment: Ok, I did the all of the things you told me, but now when I try to change the image by the following line: "ImageUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Minigame/kluis.jpg" visual studio gives me a NullReferenceException" The code looks excactly like yours. Should I have to change some value into some unique words I use in my app?

Comment: So is the image displaying correctly and then when you change the image source it gives the null reference exception? Can you put in a breakpoint and find out which object is null?

Comment: I think the OnPropertyChanged method is not filled properly. It doesn't have 2 parameters

Comment: Do you have an example of what the method should look like? I took a standard OnPropertyChanged method from MSDN

Comment: Have a look at my edit. There is no need to create another method. PropertyChanged is an event that your view will subscribe to when it binds to a property. This just tells the GUI that the property has been updated and it needs to refresh the value.

Comment: What am I a stupid man.. I am sorry, i forgot the if statement. 
Now I am trying to change the image while using the Binding. Can you maybe explain or show how this works? Thanks for your help by the way!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that your method actually succeeds and returns the correct image source? If it does there should be no problem reassigning `Source`. If you load the newly created image itself into the UI, does it retain its source?

```
this.Content = imgCreatedFromMethod;  // where "this" is the window
```

By the way, it would not be necessary to implement your own conversion function. If you have a string that would be valid as XAML, you can directly call the converter that the XAML parser uses to build an image source:

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Media;

string stringValue = ...

ImageSourceConverter converter = new ImageSourceConverter();
ImageSource imageSource = converter.ConvertFrom(
    null, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, stringValue);
```

The converter instance (an `ImageSourceConverter` in this case) can also be retrieved dynamically by `System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(TypeToConvertTo))`.

This conversion will also be done automatically if you use data-binding as in [TylerD87's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21286949/933416). You can also look into [triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.trigger(v=vs.110).aspx) and define both images in the style like this:

```
<Image>
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="original path" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger ...>
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="new path" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Comment: When I add your first line to my code, my contentscreen becomes black.

Comment: @Klyner Is `imgCreatedFromMethod.Source` null?